# django to serve same static file from different urls

Tags: javascript, django, django-urls

I have a situation where a minified js script tries to include another js file with a hard coded relative path.

More precisely :

I'm rendering an html page with url pattern `path('room/<int:room_id>/', room, name='room')`,

This page includes the first js lib with `<script src="{% static 'js/firstlib.min.js' %}"></script>`

I have `js/firstlib.min.js` in my static files dir, thus Django serve

`http://localhost:8000/static/js/firstlib.min.js correctly`.

The problem is that firstlib.min.js tries to include `tanks/lib/otherlib.js` using hardcoded relative path, using

`http://localhost:8000/room/139/tanks/lib/otherlib.js`

A dirty hack would be to replace `tank/*` with `/static/tank/*` everywhere in `firstlib.min.js`. But I'wondering if there is a better way to solve this issue, for example by dynamically rewriting url :
`/room/<int:room_id>/<path>/somescript.js` becoming `/static/<path>/somescript.js` (actually, the first script tries to include several other scripts the same way :-s)